# How to $setDirty() form using directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When the inputbox will change, then I'd like to set my form to dirty. I want to make it using directive. This is what I already did.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <type="text" ng-model="myModel" set-form-dirty>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('setFormDirty', function () {
 return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           scope.$watch(function () {
              return ngModel.$modelValue;
           }, function(newValue) {
               console.log(newValue);
            // Here I should set form to dirty. But I don't know how?
           });
        }
     };
});
```

---

@EDIT

I need this because `myModel` is changing by different function. And that function won't set form to `$dirty`

Comment: Does that "different" function which is changing the model do it inside $apply block? Please post more code where the model is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way:

```
angular.module("qs.forms").directive("setFormDirty", function () {
    return {
        require: ["ngModel", "^form"],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ctrls[0].$modelValue;
            }, function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    ctrls[1].$dirty = true;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Form could be passed by `require: ["ngModel", "^form"],`

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the modelvalue on the ngModelController.

```
.directive('setFormDirty', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        scope.$watch(function(){
          return ngModel.$modelValue;
        },function(newValue, oldValue){
          //Check stuff here and use below code to set it to dirty
          ngModel.setDirty();
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by setting the form / model to dirty? Because in essence a model is considered to be dirty when the control has been changed from when first compiled. This means that it is default behaviour for the form to have a dirty state once a value has been entered in the input field.

Comment: The problem is that this model is changing by different function. And it doesn't set form to dirty...